# How about an option to add a note when placing a bounty on someone else's question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

When placing a bounty on an old question that isn't one's own, it seems a bit odd to have to edit the question with a note as to why you're reopening it with a bounty. It would be nice to have an option to add a note, similar to a comment but just under the question and in the usual font size, explaining why you're adding the bounty.

---

This is a note about the bounty that Ian Ringrose is not placing on this question...

Comment: This is a comment which explains why I put a bounty on your question.

Comment: But it's only at the top of the comments because they weren't any others.

Comment: This is another comment explaining how I don't care enough to further this conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed, as indicated in

[Can we have a bounty remark?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102423/can-we-have-a-bounty-remark)

and documented on the blog

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/

Answer (score 1):

Why not edit the quesion to add a note?