# How to ask for a different answer to an existing question? A bounty?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

What do I do when a question exactly describes the problem I need solving - same error message and same symptoms, but the accepted answer does not solve the problem for me?

Should I add a bounty to get the question back on the radar and get other answers? Or should I re-ask the question and add a bounty to that? (Probably not, that would be a duplicate).

If I do add a bounty, how can I add any information to help solve it for my case?  Edit the question? Add comments?

The question in question: [C# HttpWebRequest SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE Intermittent Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232746/c-httpwebrequest-sec-i-renegotiate-intermittent-errors) - and was asked by someone else.

Comment: to me ... this looks like the ideal way http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102423/can-we-have-a-bounty-remark

Comment: @waffles yes that is pretty much spot on

Answer (score 6):

If you have to edit the existing question to help solve it for your case, then the question you are asking is different enough to be another question.

Just ask another question, reporting that you have already read the existing question, and in which points your question is different. This would help to avoid your question is closed as duplicate.

If the difference between the question you would ask and the question you found are not so significative (which means another answer for the existing question could help in resolving your case), then you can offer a bounty for the existing question. Keep in mind that if the question already has a detailed answer, then it is less probable a new answer will be provided.

As per post edits, those are allowed if they don't change the meaning of the post, but they fix grammatical or spelling errors, correct minor mistakes, add related resources or links, and clarify the meaning without changing it. If you are editing a question to make it a different case, then you should not edit the existing question.

Comment: The error message and the symptoms are identical, so I wont be changing the question, but might need to add more details like what my IIS settings are etc. So - comments for additional details I guess?

Comment: If you want to have a confirm that the answer doesn't change with your settings, then you can do that too. Keep in mind that users would answer to the question basing on what the question body is.